# Error while pushing application to IBM cloud

Tags: archive

I'm trying to push my application to IBM cloud but getting the following error:

Error: Unable to read archive file at - target/DAH-APP-0.0.1.war as specified in the project's manifest.yml. Please ensure that the file exists at the specified path and is accessible. Cannot complete archive push.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem. As it currently stands I do not see what this question has to do with programming or how anybody can recreate your problem. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem